# Autohotkey Replace 2 specific character with one

Tags: autohotkey

I am beginner with autohotkey.
I wanted make script which checks if I write ":)" and then it replaces with this "" (emoji in web.whatsapp)
I dont know if it's possible to do using GetKeyState because in my keyboard I need Shift+dot for ":" and Shift+9 for ")".

I am sorry about my bad english. Hope you understand. :)

Thank you.

Code that works (thank Forivin)

```
:::)::
    clipSave := ClipboardAll
    Clipboard := "" ;
    Send, ^v
    Clipboard := clipSave
Return

:::D::
    clipSave := ClipboardAll
    Clipboard := "" ;
    Send, ^v
    Clipboard := clipSave
Return
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me:

```
:::)::
    clipSave := ClipboardAll
    Clipboard := "" ;make sure this actually contains the smiley character, once you copied that into your notepad application
    Send, ^v
    Clipboard := clipSave
Return

:::(::
    clipSave := ClipboardAll
    Clipboard := "" ;make sure this actually contains the smiley character, once you copied that into your notepad application
    Send, ^v
    Clipboard := clipSave
Return
```

Make sure to save your file with the correct encoding (UTF-8 did the job for me). You may wanna use something like Notepad++ for that.
It might also help to install the unicode version Autohotkey. (I use the latest 32bit Unicode version of AHK_L.)

Comment: Thank you very much. It workd! 
Is there anyway to add more smiley characters?

Comment: You may click the check mark next to the answer now, if your question is answered now.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [Hotstrings](http://ahkscript.org/docs/Hotstrings.htm).

Example:

`:::)::`

Basically surrounding your statement with `::` followed by what you want to replace it with.

Comment: Thanks for fast reply! My code looks now like this: :::)::
return

When I do ":)" it replaces "ðŸ˜Š"..thats weird. Any help?

Comment: It likely has to do with the way AutoHotkey is encoding characters. Not familiar with a specific fix. Hopefully someone will expand on this and find an answer for you.

Comment: @user3794822 try this http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/80362-how-to-insertpaste-an-image-into-a-microsoft-word-document/

Comment: @user3794822, you (or anyone else finding their way here) have to make sure the AHK script file is a BOM-encoded file. That is, when you save your file, it can't be just an ASCII file, or even a raw UTF file, it MUST have the [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the start (for UTF-8, it's **0xEF,0xBB,0xBF**).