# Type emoji in a chat box from regular keyboard

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, emoji

I'm trying to type emoji using my regular physical keyboard by mapping them with autohotkey. 
How to get the utf-8 (or utf-16??) character(s) sent when showing, for example, this  on screen.

My current ahk code is (mapped it randomly to !+j which is alt+j):

```
!j::
Send, {U+1F601}
return
```

However, this outputs  (yes, a rectangle). 
I don't really understand how those encodings work and any help is appreciated.

Comment: Answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32331931/autohotkey-replace-2-specific-character-with-one

Comment: You have to use surrogate pairs. There is no point duplicating a post as an exact duplicate already exists. Please read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36568246/4082723